# Breaking out of UDP socket receive method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, udp

In a multithreading app i have one thread with:

```
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
```

which waits for the packet - execution is blocked with **receive** method.
Meanwhile some other thread wants to close this "waiting" thread.

How can I achieve this?

Currently I am just closing the socket which results in **SocketException** thrown, which as I suppose is not the best idea...

Any help?

Comment: You can either set a timeout in the `DatagramSocket` or you can issue an interrupt to the `Thread`.

Comment: It's not a bad idea - it's better than the wasteful, latency-ridden timeout solutions that you'll get.  Another no-waste, no-latency solution is to set a 'terminate' volatile flag and send the UDP thread an empty datagram, so making the receive() call return so it can check the flag and terminate.

Comment: ..or even send a 'please close' datagram in whatever message protocol you are using.

Comment: Good one, @martin-james

Comment: @MartinJames except that it's UDP and the sender will never know if its message truly arrived

Comment: @Raffaele - on the local stack? I doubt that it will get lost.

Comment: @MartinJames so you suggest using a socket for intra-process communication? Doesn't sound good. Also, it's not that it can be *lost*: maybe simply a configuration error, you pick the wrong destination and you'll never know

Comment: Any serious socket server doesn't want to expose a well-defined "exit" message that could be exploited by a malicious agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the socket yourself is not necessailty a bad idea: we can't say without seeing the context and telling if any design mistake is made, but I don't dislike it.

An alternative is putting the code inside a loop that checks some `volatile` flag (as it likely is already) and setting a timeout:

```
while (on) {
  //...
  datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
  datagramSocket.receive(packet);
  //...
}
```

Comment: The code is almost the same as You have entered, with the difference that **SoTimeout** is set to 0. I wanted the socket to be open always. In Your case it is opened only for 5 seconds. he problem is that when I even set the **on** variable to false it does not stop the thread as it is waiting at **receive** method.

Comment: @Pisek either you expose a flag and set a timeout or you expose the  implementation (socket and/or thread)

Comment: @Pisek The socket is opened when you construct it and closed when you close it. The socket is *receiving* for five seconds here. Your objection doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP, I meant _open and receiving always_